# Как совершить переход на следующий месяц при расчете даты?

Tags: javascript

Хотелось бы уточнить, как сделать +1 шаг в месяце, если дата будет превышать 30 или 31 день. То есть есть код который получает count, где число задается от пользователя. Оно может быть как 1 так и 30 ну или 60. Но если просто вывести циклом, на 30м или 31м дне, у меня идет 32, 33, и т.д. Пробовал через условие и break, но все не то. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это возможно сделать.
Код:

```
function getDate(count){
let result = [];
let data = new Date();
let getDates = {
    day: data.getDate(),
    month: data.getMonth(),
    year: data.getFullYear(),
}
let daysInMonth = new Date(getDates.month, getDates.year, 0).getDate();
for(let i = 1; i < count; i++){
    result.push(`${getDates.day + i}.${getDates.month + 1}.${getDates.year}`);

    if(i % daysInMonth == 0){

        getDates.day = 1;
        getDates.month += 1;
        break
    }
}
return result;
```

}

Comment: Присмотрись к библиотеке `date-fns`, к функции `addMonth` https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/addMonths. Если к 31 января прибавишь месяц, получишь 28 февраля, тебе это нужно?

Answer (score 0):

ну нужно вводить дополнительную сущность в виде getDates, чтобы потом решать проблемы, которые она несет. Уже есть дата - data, вот с ней и надо работать. Туда и прибавлять. Вот так например `data.setDate(date.getDate() + number)`